# Old questions that are now irrelevant or even completely wrong?

Tags: discussion

I just came across this old question about Spotify: [Cannot get Spotify to run](https://askubuntu.com/questions/62881/cannot-get-spotify-to-run/62888#comment527483_62888).

Back in 2011, we needed Premium accounts to use the Linux-version. That's no longer the case. So, what do we do with these? It's obviously not a good thing if we have lots of wrong answers.

Comment: Suggestions: 1) Put a note on the answer that it only applies to 2011, 2) Close too localised, 3) Post a new answer with current situation

Comment: [I'm asking how the rest of SE deals with this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217325/how-should-ask-ubuntu-handle-old-questions-and-answers). It's not just a problem of *what to do* but a question on how we deal with the scale. Thousands and thousands of questions have this problem.

Comment: That entire question needs to be nuked from orbit. Just to be sure!